# How to change a node add form without changing the node edit form

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, nodes

I'm using drupal 7

I'm writing a custom hook_form_alter something like this

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == "rating_node_form")
        {
            // Do something
        }
}
```

it seems that both the node add form and the node edit form are using the same form ID. I'm wondering if there is a way to determine weather you are editing or adding a node and make changes to the form accordingly. Do they always have to be the same exact form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[node_object_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7), which is called from `node_form()` (the form builder for the node editing form), executes the following snippet to verify if a node is being added, or edited:

```
  // If this is a new node, fill in the default values.
  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    foreach (array('status', 'promote', 'sticky') as $key) {
      // Multistep node forms might have filled in something already.
      if (!isset($node->$key)) {
        $node->$key = (int) in_array($key, $node_options);
      }
    }
    global $user;
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
  }
```

In your case, you could use code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "rating_node_form") {
    $node = $form_state['node'];
    if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
      // The node is new.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Or you can check if the second argument `arg(1) == 'add'`

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'rating_node_form' && arg(1) == 'add') {
        // Do something
  }
}
```